Hokkien female name "In"
Chinese Indonesian here.  I've been trying to figure out how to write my wife's Chinese name in Chinese.  It has the word "In" in it, but neither she nor he parents know what that means (go figure!).  Like a lot of Chinese Indonesian, we are Hokkien.
What could "In" possibly mean?  Understand it could mean so many things, but anything close would be good enough.

Varied in the accurate pronunciation (tone and nasal), the word can be yin such as 茵, or ying such as 颖莹樱瑛英莺. These words are common in a female first name (not family name). I Consulted a friend who speaks Hokkien a little and living in Fujian province. Hope it helps.

Thank you (and yes, it is her first/given name)
